# CDK: How to add custom event bus (in another account) to event rule (in another account)?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I have a **account A** where event rule is present. I have **account B** where I have custom event bus which should act as target to event rule in account A.

I did refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64069765/how-do-i-specify-another-aws-accounts-event-bus-as-a-target-of-an-eventbridge-r) but this is in cloudformation.

**I am passing another account custom event bus arn as props.**

Here is my code, upon running cdk deploy it shows error of stating cannot find resource of undefined length

```
const eventRule = new events.Rule(this, 'event-rule', {
  ruleName: getResourceName(this, 'event-rule', 'rule-name', props.envName),
  description: 'This rule will be used to capture events',
  eventPattern: {"source": ['source']},
})
    
    
eventRule.addTarget(new eventTarget.EventBus(props.anotherAccountEventBusArn))
```

Comment: Does this provide any help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-cross-account.html

Comment: I have read this article, and conceptually I understood but I am looking something how to approach this using aws CDK

Comment: Please post the full error. Does `cdk synth` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `event_targets.EventBus` constructor takes an argument of type `IEventBus`, but you are passing a string.

To create a construct representing a reference to an actual event bus, use `EventBus.fromEventBusArn`. Here is an example from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events_targets.EventBus.html):

```
rule.addTarget(new targets.EventBus(
  events.EventBus.fromEventBusArn(
    this,
    'External',
    `arn:aws:events:eu-west-1:999999999999:event-bus/test-bus`,
  ),
));
```

Your target Event Bus must have a resource policy that allows the source account to put events into it.